# How can I keep a charged particle between two capacitor plates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, charge, capacitance

To make this practical, let's make a problem out of it. And our problem would be explained as follows:
We have a small sphere that weighs x kg and is placed inbetween two parallell plates in an air-filled capacitor.

[image: capacitor plates with sphere between them]

We could have the sphere be any positive charge q and the area of the plates 225 cm^2. That distance d between the plates is d = 1.0 cm.

What would the voltage U over the capacitor need to be in order for the sphere to stay still like it's shown in the picture?

I solved it by combining:
$$C = \frac{Q}{U} $$ and $$ C=\varepsilon _{0}\frac{A}{d} $$
to
$$U=\frac{1}{\varepsilon _{0}}\frac{Q\cdot d}{A}$$
$$U=\frac{1}{8.854\cdot 10^{-12}}\cdot \frac{10\cdot10^{-10}\cdot 0.01 }{225\cdot 10^{-10}}$$
$$U=502.2 V$$

But I'm not very confident in my answer to this problem. I'm learning physics as a hobby outside college so alot of the time there is something trivial I'm missing out on. For example, I'm not sure how I could take into account the weight of the sphere? I'm sure it should affect our answer somehow.

Comment: Where and how does the mass come into play? And no, I'm afraid this isn't correct. The formula between $Q$ and $U$ are related to the voltage and charge *of the capacitor*. You need to determine the force acting on the particle that balances gravity, and then the electric field necessary for that force to be exerted, and then the voltage for the capacitor that will result in that electric field.

Comment: Are you trying to do Millikan's Experiment?

Comment: @Andras Deak thank you for pointing me in the right direction. If you have time to make a full answer I'd love it, but otherwise thanks for the tips.

Comment: @pfnuesel No, I found this question in an old swedish physics book(without answer), and was like wow that's interesting. The other problems on capacitors were quite dull

Comment: That's exactly Millikan's Experiment though (or at least a special case of it). You might want to read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to balance the electric force $F_e$ with the gravitational one $F_g$: $$\vec{F_e}=-\vec{F_g}.$$
Then, if the plates are big enough with respect to the sphere you have that
$$
F_e=q E=\frac{qV}{d}.
$$
In the end:
$$
\frac{qV}{d}=mg\Rightarrow V=\frac{mgd}{q}.
$$

Comment: Wow so simple and elegant. This is my problem, when I switch over to electromagnetics I forget that the rules of mechanics still apply, like gravitational force.

Thank you for your explanation to this problem.

Comment: Of course you need the negative-charged plate to be on the top if you have a positive-charged sphere.

Comment: Yes exactly otherwise both the electric field force and gravitational force will be pushing it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel plates produce a uniform electric field $E=\frac U d$ between the plates where $d$ is the separation of the plates.
From this you can find the force due to this electric field on the mass.
Then equate it to the weight of the mass so that the net force on the mass is zero.

So the capacitance formula is redundant.